# java.sql.SQLException: URL is not in the correct format

Tags: gwt, tomcat, tomcat6

I am using tomcat, Java with GWT. When try to connect to db my applcation spews the following error. the same driver information is perfectly running on stand alone application.

> java.sql.SQLException: URL is not in the correct format:
>   jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=XXXX_cachedb_devc;uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXXX
>           at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.driverUrlNotInCorrectFormat(Exceptions.java:103)
>           at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:47)
>           at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:24)
>           at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>           at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)

May i know how can i over come this problem.

Comment: Can you show us some code? The part where you enter database details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like either you are trying to deploy to App Engine or somehow how appengine jars are in your runtime classpath. 
If you are not planning to deploy your application at Google App Engine, simply remove the app engine SDK jars from your project.

On the other hand, if you want to deploy to app engine,  do know that GAE does not yet support connecting to external databases. All you can do is to use in-memory SQL databases like hsqldb. Your connection url then needs to conform to the hsqldb connection url pattern for in-memory databases.

Comment: Thanks tahir, I removed three app engine jars from my runtime classpath. Let me give a try and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Tahir, No i am not deploying to app engine.

Comment: Confirming that tahir is correct. Thanks tahir Its working well.